# Which are the correct ways of making modifications in existing codebase from another vendor?

Tags: php

Lets suppose we have downloaded PHP source codes of some product (framework or CMS for example) of some vendor.

After examination of source code, it was found that some parts of it should be slightly (a change of 1-2 lines) modified in order to integrate properly with our application.

Is there any well-known technique for doing such modifications? Imagine, we've changed something and after that vendor releases a new version of its product and we should manually compare all files in order to transfer our modifications to the new version. Are there any ways to avoid such issues? Maybe there are some command-line tools, which can simplify it?

**EDIT**
Just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973021/what-are-some-strategies-to-facilitate-relatively-heavy-modification-of-vendors?rq=1
Answer of [@Breton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51101/breton) mentions using GIT and 2 separate branches. We can go with that, but maybe someone knows other ways to do that?
In our case modifications in vendor code are very small (1-2 lines) ...

Comment: Is it class that you can inherit into a sub-class - then you just write the method that needs tweaking?

Comment: No, its a huge amount of code based on Zend Framework (SocialEngine, to be precise, but my question is neither about it nor about Zend Framework). Code provides events, but they are not always fired and we need to call event dispatcher in the places we need and with our custom events. This is 2 lines modification, but it should be done in vendor code, that's why we worry about integration of vendor code updates.

Comment: It will mostly depend on your version control system and what 3rd part product exactly you're talking about. git can make this really easy, there may be strategies for doing it in SVN, or the best way may simply be to override/extend/configure the 3rd party code without modifying it directly.

Comment: @deceze, override/extend/configure is not an option in our case. Vendor code does not provide such ability. Plugins can be written for it, but they all have very limited points of integration with core.

Comment: In my opinion, you have only two options.  Either you override/extend/configure, or you submit your changes to the vendor and get it included.  If you aren't doing one of these, then you'll have a mess on your hands down the road when you upgrade.  I've seen these small 1-2 line changes stack up and be forgotten and cause major problems for developers 2 or 3 years down the road too many times.  Remember, every time an engineer changes vendor code a puppy dies.

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser, vendor should provide ability to override/extend/configure, otherwise it is impossible to do it. In my case I have SocialEngine, which is not also NOT documented but also poorly written (when you look into code it seems that someone was hurrying to get to the last train). And due to lack of essential support (related contacts at least :) ) I cannot also submit changes to vendor. But the question is not about it. Maybe there is an option to mark tiny changes in source code (like CVS does) and using some tool merge them automatically if it is possible? That's my question.

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser, I think I'm going to kill a lot of puppies :D